# js.coffee.erb throwing an error due to å æ ø character fetched from DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, coffeescript

Env: Rails 3.2.11 app

In assets/javascript

I have this file home.js.coffee.erb :

```
jQuery ($) ->
  $.supersized

    # Functionality
    slide_interval: 3000 # Length between transitions
    transition: 3 # 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
    transition_speed: 700 # Speed of transition
    thumbnail_navigation: 0

    # Components                            
    slide_links: "blank" # Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'num', 'name', 'blank')
    slides: [
<% for cs in CreativeService.where('active') %>
      image: "<%= cs.featured_image.url %>"
      title: "<%= cs.art.name %> > <%= cs.title %> by <%= cs.artist.first_name %> <%= cs.artist.last_name[0]  %>"
      thumb: "<%= cs.featured_image.url(:small) %>"
      url: "/creative_services/<%= cs.id %>"
    ,
<% end %>
    ]
```

This evaluates correctly on my dev environment but then I get this error once deployed to HEROKU

```
throw Error("Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError: \"\\xC3\" on US-ASCII\n  (in /app/app/assets/javascripts/home.js.coffee.erb)")
```

The error seems to be due to characters fetched from the database å æ ø (Iam working with norwegian language)

<%= cs.title %>  <= what can I do to this string to prevent that error?

In my Gemfile:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "~> 3.2.5"

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.2.2"     <= outside or inside the group doesn't help
```

I have tried adding these in the application.rb file but it didn't help:

```
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
```

Also add this at the beginning of the js.coffee.erb file, still without success:

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

LAST FINDING:

I figured that the errors happens because of the text fetched from the database.

Comment: Do you use a Supersized - a fullscreen background slideshow built using the jQuery library?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
heroku config:set LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: unfortunately that didn't help. thx for the suggestion. I am not sure I understand what the message is telling me

Comment: Do you think is possible you can have an invisible character breaking things?, although I am not sure how to detect it, these appear with `git log -p -- app/assets/javascripts/home.js.coffee` but could be diffidult to spot

Comment: juan, I figured that the code itself is fine but I am fetching data from a database and those strings contain Norwegian characters. (If I put plain text it works, he I get the data it fails.) Can those be the problem and how would I force the strings from the database utf-8 ?